# Shared Templates in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I've got a bunch of useful Project Item templates for Visual Studio 2010 and I'd like to share them with the developers in my team.  At the moment the zip files are sitting on a network share with an instructions text file telling users to copy the zips deep into their  Documents folders.

I'd much rather have Visual Studio look in the share for its templates, or have some similar way of synchronizing a central repository of templates - especially since these particular templates are very likely to be updated in the future.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the 'User project templates location' and 'User item templates location' properties in VS:  Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General

Comment: That's just what I was looking for!  Thanks!